# What is a word for someone that is not mature enough to handle power/opportunity/leeway?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I say "Joe, you can have flexible work hours as long as you finish your work  and maintain a regular presence in the office", and Joe comes into work once a week.  Joe is _______.

I want to convey a situation where the conditions are subject to interpretation within a reasonable range, but the person in question skirts the low end of that range.

Comment: I don't understand the attitude of the boss. If Joe is finishing his work, then he is abiding by the condition given to him.

Comment: But if Joe is taking paid time off 80% of the time and **not** finishing his work, then in common parlance he is **abusing the privilege** that the boss granted him.

Comment: ......Immature.

Comment: @Clare Maybe it would be better to switch "unlimited paid time off" with "flexible work hours" and "finish your work" with "finish your work and maintain a regular presence in the office". Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with ***irresponsible***:

> ***[irresponsible](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/irresponsible)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> (of a person, attitude, or action) not showing a proper sense of responsibility.
>   *[with infinitive] ‘it would have been irresponsible just to drive on’*

At least, that's what I use with my kids.